# One JavaScript function runs, but two don't?

Tags: javascript, function, button, submit

I have a large Ruby on Rails form that has the following partial view structure (file _form.html.erb)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction1() {

        ... some js code here

    }

    function applyConfigs() {

        ... some js code here

    }

</script>

<%= form_for(@test, :html => {:name => "Test", :id => "test_form"}) do |f| %>

    ... some Ruby code here

    <div class="actions">
        <input type=button value="Run Function1" onclick="myFunction1();">
    </div>

    ... some Ruby code here

    <div class="actions">
        <input type=submit value="Apply" onclick="applyConfigs();">
    </div>

<% end %>
```

In this situation, none of the functions gets called when I click "Run Function1" or "Apply" buttons (the buttons highlight but do nothing). But if I put each function in a separate

```
<script>
</script>
```

therefore having 2 script /script sections containing one function each, then function `myFunction1()` gets executed properly but `applyConfigs()` still does not (the form is submitted but `applyConfigs()` function is not executed). There are no error messages in any case, just the functions not executed.

Any idea what's going on here?

My function `applyConfigs()` is quite large but here's my other function that I called `myFunction1()`

```
function showHideDiv(elementId,buttonId) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
        if (element.style.display == 'none') {
            element.style.display = 'block';
            button.value = "Hide Options";
            return false;
        } else if (element.style.display == 'block') {
            element.style.display = 'none';
            button.value = "Show Options";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing I see is that you have a semi-colon ; after your function call. Try removing them.

Comment: And maybe give us your JavaScript code, it could be really useful.

Comment: The semicolons are valid (you can have multiple statements in even handler)

Comment: I re-edited my post and added one of the functions ; the other one is quite large

Comment: it turns out my problem is that the 2nd function contains a syntax error, but I receive no warning about it when I load the form or click the button. Further more, if I have multiple js functions in the same script /script section each called by a separate button and all working fine, but if I purposely introduce a syntax error in only one of the functions, then all those functions become useless, without any error or warning message! this is just terrible and I can't beleive it is true, I tested it many times to prove it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input type submit will submit the form. You need to change it:

```
<div class="actions">
 <input type="button" value="Apply" onclick="applyConfigs();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper name is onClick with a capital C but that shouldn't matter.  Assuming your javascript is error free...  Try using the [onSubmit](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html) event for the apply button.  I think that's what you want.  onSubmit even lets your conditionally cancel the form submission.

Comment: I changed to onClick and also onSubmit but still the same issue ;-(